# Setting a SelectOneListbox default selection, which is populated from a hashmap

Tags: jsf, primefaces, selectonelistbox

I have a selectOneListBox that is populated with a hashmap's key as the label and the value as the value.

How do i set the first object in the list as the default selection, so it looks highlighted

```
<!--the list box containing the results from the search-->
    <h:form id="newPointsResultList" styleClass="simpleformstyle">
        <p:selectOneListbox id="selectedPoints_listbox" 
                            value="#{mapBean.selectedPoint}" 
                            converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter" 
                            scrollHeight="395" 
                            styleClass="simpleformstyle10" 
                            rendered="#{not empty mapBean.newPointsHashMap}" >

            <f:selectItems value="#{mapBean.newPointsHashMap}" />

            <p:ajax listener="#{mapBean.valueChanged}" update=":newPointsGrid:selectedPoint_grid" process="@this" />
            <f:param name="idUser" value="#{mapBean.tipTourUser.idUser}" />
        </p:selectOneListbox>
    </h:form>
    <br />
```

Answer (score 0):

I set the mapBean.selectedPoint to the value of the first object in the hashmap, and then the selectOneListBox highlights the default selection